# Purge older data from MsSql

Tags: sql-server, azure

What would be the best way to automaticall backup and purge old data from a mssql server (hosted on Azure).

It contains logs (which needs to be inside a database, because we have an application analyzing it realtime) of a webserver. However, data that's older than, lets say, a week doesn't need to be available realtime.

My table contains a column containing the date it is added.

What would be the most efficient way to do this. I obviously thought about using a cron job with a bunch of queries. But is there some features in either azure or mssql that could facilitate this (or perhaps some other software).

Thanks!

Comment: How about creating a SQL Job and to schedule it as per your requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately SQL Agent is not available for SQL Azure, so there's no way to create jobs using this feature like on-premises SQL Server but it doesn't mean you don't have alternatives. Cron job is ok, but I have a few more suggestions you should consider:

1. [SQL Database Elastic Jobs](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-jobs-overview/)
2. [Azure job scheduler](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/scheduler/)
3. [Azure Automation](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/automation/)
4. [SQL Server in a VM](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ms-tech_learning_with_prasant/archive/2014/07/09/scheduling-job-on-sql-azure.aspx) - In case you have one, you could use it to create remote jobs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have large volumes of data then the most efficient mechanism for purging data would be to use table partitioning. You have a column for the date which would be perfect as a partition column. 
For example if you partition by year then you can delete an entire year of data by dropping that partition. A delete could take hours and fill your transaction log whereas dropping a partition is immediate. I use this technique for a table that only stores 7 days of data and we store around 20 Gb per day on an overloaded server. Deleting a day of data takes about 3 hours and is a performance drain whereas dropping that day's partition is instantaneous. It also makes our queries read faster.
So you just a need a job to create the new partitions and drop the old partitions you want to purge (based on your data retention policy).